# flask application with dbt-potgres in same container

Tags: python, docker, flask, dbt

I am trying to run flask application in the same conatiner where i have my dbt-postgres and planning to to pass the dbt execution commands as POST API parameters.
Flask application is running fine but whenever I try to run dbt cli command it kiled by itself.

should dbt-postgres and flask application run in same container?

[image]

Comment: Could they run in one container: yes; should you run them in one container: most likely not.

Comment: is there any possible reason why dbt command is killed? it is working fine if I terminate flask application.

Comment: Most common reason get killed is use more memory than it allowed. I have experienced reason on a small VM. it get killed without any extra information